# MySQL PHP Search using one input to search multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, database

First of sorry for my English, But i'll try to make my idea clear.
My goal : use one input field to search in multiple columns. i'll give an example to make it easier and clear for u guys to understand.

I've many CPUs for different brand. so if i'm going to write "CPU" it will give me all CPUs for all brands, but if i'm going to continue writing "CPU Lenovo" it will show me the CPU only for lenovo brand. so more detail gives more specific results.

here is my code :

```
<?php

require ('connection.php');

if (!empty($_POST['partname'])) {
    $search = explode(" ", rtrim($_POST['partname'], " "), 2);

    $prlist_name = "";
    $prlist_model = "";
    foreach ($search AS $s) {

        $prlist_name .= "`prlist_name` LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($s) . "%' AND ";
        $prlist_model .= "`prlist_model` LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($s) . "%' OR ";
    }

    $prlist_name = substr($prlist_name, 0, -4);
    $prlist_model = substr($prlist_model, 0, -4);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `prlist` WHERE ($prlist_name) AND ($prlist_model)");

    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['prlist_name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['prlist_model'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
} else {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
?>
```

The problem with my code is searching separately. i mean that if i'm going to write "CPU Lenovo". it will show me the whole parts for Lenovo. example:

1. CPU | Lenovo G580
2. RAM | Lenovo T430
3. CPU | Lenovo Z500

That's it. Thanks all :)

Comment: you should find about Boolean Full-Text Searches in mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM prlist WHERE MATCH (prlist_name,prlist_model)
AGAINST ('+CPU +Lenovo' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html